# Magento 2.3.7-p3 Unable to save extension attribute to Quote Item

Tags: magento2, quote, plugin, quoteitem, extension-attributes

I want to show customers how many 'points' they could be making, per quote item, on each item row of the basket. Using extension attributes, this is what I have:

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="add_points_to_quote" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\AddPointsToCartItems"/>
</type>
```

extension_attributes.xml

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="points" type="int"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

db_schema.xml

```
<table name="quote_item" resource="default" engine="innodb">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="points" padding="30" unsigned="false" nullable="true" comment="Points"/>
</table>
```

and finally my plugin

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

public function beforeGetList(CartItemRepositoryInterface $subject, $cartId)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    /** @var CartItemInterface $cartItem */
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $cartItem) {
        $resultAttributes = $cartItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        $resultAttributes->setPoints(102); //Arbitrary number
        $cartItem->setExtensionAttributes($resultAttributes);
    }
}
```

I can error_log the **$cartItem->getExtensionAttributes();** and it will return my set value. But nothing is saved to the database & using (in cart/item/default.phtml) **$_item->getPoints()** or **$_item->getExtensionAttributes()->getPoints()** does not return anything.

I'm very certain I'm missing a step somewhere.

The render on default.phtml works if I manually enter a number into the database on the quote_item table, so does **$cartItem->setExtensionAttributes($resultAttributes)** not also set the value in the database?

Comment: I have found another way to do the same thing. Using the schema edit above, I'm able to use an Observer triggered by "checkout_cart_product_add_after" and  "sales_quote_item_qty_set_after" to set and get points in the sales_quote_item table using the extension already created. I'm sure this isn't the correct way so I'll leave this open in case I or someone has a better one!

Comment: Hey, try the same as You did with plugn, but use After plugin, instead of Before. 
Also remember, to return proper values in plugins :) Fir Before Plugin, You have to return parameters as array, and for After, Yu have to return the same type as in main method